# Show negative values in Deneb column chart in red

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

I've been playing around with the Deneb visual in PowerBI Desktop and (amongst many other things) have been trying to create a simple column chart that shows negative values in red and positive values in green, however can't for the life of me seem to get it working - I believe the condition/test in my script is correct, but it refuses to 'fire' when it's 'true'

I've read through the condition page of the Vega-Lite documentation https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/condition.html and have a condition section within the encoding/color

I've added Month End and MonthYear columns from my Calendar table and an EBITDA measure from a fact table to the Deneb visual

| Month End | MonthYear | EBITDA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/7/2021 | "Jul-21" | 8277.56 |
| 31/8/2021 | "Aug-21" | -15123.66 |
| 30/9/2021 | "Sep-21" | 9502.11 |
| 31/10/2021 | "Oct-21" | 13090.99 |

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "MonthYear",
      "sort": {"field": "Month End"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "EBITDA",
      "aggregate": "sum"
    },
    "color": {
      "condition": {
        "test": "datum['EBITDA']<0",
        "value": "red"
      },
      "value": "green"
    }
  }
}
```

If I adjust the condition to be `"test": "1==1"` then the 'true' path works, so I assume I've got something wrong with my test line, though this seems to be correct per a lot of blogs, stackoverflow questions etc.

I've also tried using a `"tranform:"` channel to create a new Neg field in the Deneb dataset and referring to that field in my test, but it still won't adjust the colour.

[image: Deneb screenshot]
[image: With Neg field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t like your aggregation. It looks like the data you are sending in is already aggregated by Power BI. If so, this will work:

```json
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
```

[View sample in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDSACCikEzT8ATAA4AvgpNoQAIUvXUYsc9foAMJeaAAsAMz+IKYAIiGoAJwAjFGmAKLx9iku0W4AYvFikTmmAOLxSQmpbgASmQDs1egAkoW2jgC6ziDIAE4A1m5MSL2WcLJQbMo0smRooAAe8yAAZjRwgspuKEoyvZjLaxtb6CiO3QCeh+ubQ5aYFzhwbgCODEiymHRqNKQg3ZNBGxRpoQJNZNMvnJlph9Ad0KpMAwEIYAORMVEdAA8AAZLNpdM90L04FtugS9G4yCTxv9zkA)

If your data isn’t aggregated, add an aggregate transform like this:

```json
  "transform": [
    {"aggregate": [{
       "op": "sum",
       "field": "b",
       "as": "bsum"
      }],
      "groupby": ["a"]}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "a",
      "sort": {"field": "a"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "bsum",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": {
      "condition": {
        "test": "datum['bsum']<0",
        "value": "red"
      },
      "value": "green"
    }
  }
}
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoDSACCikEzT8ATAA4AvgpNoQAIUvXUYsc9foAMJeaAAsAMz+IKYAIiGoAJwAjFGmAKLx9iku0W4AYvFikTmmAOLxSQmpbgASmQDs1egAkoW2jgC6ziCYAE5IshAAZmy9CEYmZGS9fJhwEyBsOG4QDONKQzRwgspu1kpIBuhMq+OdStNsDDhMAJ5GuV0dSsi9ANZ7SL2WcLJQbMoaLIyGhQAAPUEgTbbXboFBKGS9TCQ6E7NwoRzde6aKFbNHHU6WTC3HDzdAARwYA0wdDUNFIIG6-0Eo0h-1kgJpckhcwgyPQqkwa0MAHITmsRR0ADwABks2l0ZJAM123QVejc0zgv0ZmKAA)

Comment: ahh brilliant, thankyou, the removal of the aggregate and changing the type to quantitative solve it